# What is the name of this variant of n choose k but with multiple subsets to pick?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, algorithms

$n$ choose $k$ can be seen as permuting a binary string with $k$ of the digits set to $1$, and $n - k$ of them to $0$. For example if the string is length $n=6$ and $k=3$, one permutation would be:

$$0,0,0,1,1,1 \rightarrow 1,0,0,1,1,0$$

I am interested in understanding a variant of this where a string with equal numbers of $0,1,2,3...m$ is permuted. For example, if the string is length $n=12$ and $m=3$, one permutation would be:
$$0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3 \rightarrow 1,0,0,1,3,3,2,3,1,0,2,2$$

I know this is related to $n$ choose $k$ and permutations. I am wondering: is there a specific name for what I am describing?

I am interested in finding a ranking function for this object I am describing. That is, forming a bijection with $f:\{1,2,…,g(n,m)\}→S$, where $g(n,m)$ is the number of possible strings for that $n$ and $m$, and $S$ is the set of all strings. Then, $f(1)$ is the first string, $f(2)$ is the second, etc. The closest thing I found forming this kind of mapping was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506078/fast-permutation-number-permutation-mapping-algorithms).

Comment: I think what you are asking for is a [ranking function](http://oeis.org/wiki/Ranking_and_unranking_functions#:~:text=A%20ranking%20algorithm%20determines%20the,be%20considered%20as%20inverse%20operations.) for these strings. That is, not a bijection with $\mathbb Z$, but a bijection with $f:\{1,2,\dots,g(n,m)\}\to S$, where $g(n,m)$ is the number of possible strings for that $n$ and $m$, and $S$ is the set of all strings. Then, $f(1)$ is the first string, $f(2)$ is the second, etc. Does that sound like what you are looking for?

Comment: **If** I am interpreting your question correctly, it looks like you are interested in [multinomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).  In the cited article, it doesn't seem that you are interested in the *probability theory* aspect of the article.  However, it does seem as if you are interested in the portion of the article that deals with enumeration.  For the specific problem that you posed, **again if** I am interpreting your question correctly, the enumeration is $$\binom{12}{3}\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3} = \frac{(12)!}{(3!) ~(3!) ~(3!) ~(3!)}.$$

Comment: I think you may be asking about the [permutations of a multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets).

Comment: Thank you all so much for you comments.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, yes that is what I am looking for. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: @user2661923 yes, I am interested in the enumeration part, the 'ranking function'.

Comment: @awkward ok, that is exaclty what I was describing! Perfect. This is a 'permutation of a multiset'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to my question, this is a permutation of a multiset.